# Method "Astronomy/execute" not found in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-react

Okay, I build Game DB schema using astronomy package in meteor.

Then I try to add method to it by extending it in server. (server/gamehandle.js)

```
import {Game} from '../imports/db/game'
import {DDP} from 'meteor/ddp-client'

Game.extend({
  meteorMethods: {
    AddNewGame(judul){
      const invocation = DDP._CurrentInvocation.get()
      this.namaGame = judul
      this.creator = invocation.userId
      this.createdAt = new Date()
      return this.save()
    }
  }
})
```

But when I try to run the method in app client using callMethod it throw an error that astronomy/execute not found 404.
This the component using it

```
import {Game} from '../../../db/game'

export function NewGameList(props){
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()
  const [judul, setJudul] = useState('')
  const [hasil, setHasil] = useState(null)
  const judulChange = (e) => setJudul(e.target.value)
  const AddGame = new Game()
  
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    AddGame.callMethod('AddNewGame', judul, (err, result) => {
      result ? setHasil(result) : setHasil(err.message) 
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
...
```

So enlight me, what thing I do wrong?

Comment: Silly question, but did you import `server/gamehandle.js` from your main server file, i.e., have you verified that the `Game.extend` code is called? Everything else seems in order.

Comment: I am now adding it directly to Game class so it can be called directly in client (and removing method call of course). But still have the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution from meteor slack.
Just need to imports my db file to main js file in server.